# How to use fade in jquery for prepend?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I want to use fade in effect for my prepend function.

I have tried follow one but it is not working.

```
$('#iq').prepend('.....').fadeIn('slow')
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try the example below.

```
$('#test').prepend($('<div id="bob">Hi der</div>').fadeIn('slow'));
```

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dKwkd/)**

Since you are just fading in the elements you are prepending just do it within the `prepend` as you add them, this also has the benefit of not forcing you to hide them first.

Answer (score 6):

[`prepend`](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/) returns the elements in the object you call it on, not the *new* elements, so you're calling `fadeIn` on the elements you're pre-pending the new content to. Instead, you want [`prependTo`](http://api.jquery.com/prependTo/), which is basically `prepend` the other way 'round. (See the docs for details.) Also, you need to `hide` the new elements before fading them in, so:

```
$('.......').prependTo('#iq').hide().fadeIn('slow');
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/ucaze5)

Answer (score 2):

The element needs to be hidden first:

```
$('#iq').hide().prepend('.....').fadeIn('slow');
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem: You have many div created new with prepend
Solution: Add first new div with display:none and a class after prepend call class to get visible.

```
$('#putin').prepend('<div id="test" class="5" style="display:none">test1</div>');
$('.5').slideDown('slow');
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KEU67/)